# org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ОШИБКА: столбец нельзя автоматически привести к типу

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Делаю CRUD приложение на Spring Boot, подключены зависимость Spring Web и PostgreSQL. В ней была такая  таблица:

```
create table dogs (id int not null generated by default as identity primary key, nickname varchar(20) not null, name varchar(40), breed varchar(30), date_of_birth timestamp without time zone, puppies_count int);
```

Добавил в нее несколько записей, в т.ч. в колонку `breed`. Затем решил изменить тип этой колонки на `enum`:
очистил колонку, создал перечисление и изменил тип столбца с текстового на это перечисление:

```
update dogs set breed = null;
create type breed as enum ('WHWT', 'SCOTTISH_T', 'SEALYHAM_T', 'JRT', 'AUSTRALIAN_S', 'METIS', 'OTHER');
alter table dogs alter column breed set data type breed using breed::breed;
```

После этого Eclipse стал выдавать такую ошибку:

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ОШИБКА: столбец "breed" нельзя автоматически привести к типу smallint
  Подсказка: Возможно, необходимо указать "USING breed::smallint".
```

Пробовал делать как в подсказке - не работает.
И откуда попытка привести это к smallint?

Сущность:

```
package com.example.demo6.entities;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;


import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.Size;


@Entity
@Table(name = "dogs")
public class Dog {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @NotBlank(message = "Nickname should not be empty")
    @Size(min = 3, max = 30, message = "Nickname should be between 3 and 30 characters long")
    private String nickname;
    @Size(min = 3, max = 30, message = "Name should be between 3 and 30 characters long")
    private String name;
    private Breed breed;
    @Column(name = "date_of_birth")
    private LocalDateTime dateOfBirth;
    @Column(name = "puppies_count")
    private int puppies;
    
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNickname() {
        return nickname;
    }

    public void setNickname(String nickname) {
        this.nickname = nickname;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Breed getBreed() {
        return breed;
    }

    public void setBreed(Breed breed) {
        this.breed = breed;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getDateOfBirth() {
        return dateOfBirth;
    }

    public void setDateOfBirth(LocalDateTime dateOfBirth) {
        this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
    }

    public int getPuppies() {
        return puppies;
    }

    public void setPuppies(int puppies) {
        this.puppies = puppies;
    }

    public Dog() {}
    
    public enum Breed {
        WHWT("Вест Хайленд Вайт Терьер"), 
        SCOTTISH_T("Скотч Терьер"), 
        SEALYHAM_T("Силихем Терьер"), 
        JRT("Джек Рассел Терьер"), 
        AUSTRALIAN_S("Австралийская овчарка"), 
        METIS("Метис/Дворняга"),
        OTHER("Другая");
        
        Breed(String breed){}
    }
}
```

Контроллер:

```
package com.example.demo6.controllers;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import com.example.demo6.entities.Dog;
import com.example.demo6.service.DogService;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class DogController {
    private DogService dogService;
    
    
    @Autowired
    public DogController(DogService dogService) {       
        this.dogService = dogService;
    }

    public DogService getDogService() {
        return dogService;
    }

    public void setDogService(DogService dogService) {
        this.dogService = dogService;
    }

    @GetMapping("")
    public String index(Model model) {  
        model.addAttribute("dog", new Dog());
        model.addAttribute("dogs", dogService.findAll());
        return "index";
    }
    
    @PostMapping("")
    public String add(@ModelAttribute("dog") Dog dog, Model model) {    
        dogService.save(dog);
        return "redirect:/";
    }
    
}
```

Главная страница:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="https://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Собаки</title>
 <style>
   table { 
    width: 100%; 
    border: 4px double black; 
    border-collapse: collapse; 
   }
   th { 
    text-align: left; 
    background: #ccc; 
    padding: 5px; 
    border: 1px solid black; 
   }
   td { 
    padding: 5px; 
    border: 1px solid black; 
   }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<div th:if="${isUserAuth}">Выйти</div>
<div th:unless="${isUserAuth}">Войти</div>
<div sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()">
    <p>user@ukr.net</p> <a href="/logout">Logout</a>  
</div>

<div sec:authorize="!isAuthenticated()">
    <p>Hello, guest! Please <a href="/login">Login</a> or <a href="/signup">SignUp</a></p> 
</div>
<table border="1" color="black" border-collapse="collapse">
    <tr>
        <td><b>ID</b></td>
        <td><b>Кличка</b></td>
        <td><b>Имя</b></td>
        <td><b>Порода</b></td>
        <td><b>Дата рождения</b></td>
        <td><b>Щенки</b></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <form modelAttribute="dog" th:method="POST" th:object:"${dog}" th:action="@{/}" action="#">
            <td><input type="submit" value="Добавить"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" th:field="*{dog.nickname}" id="dog.nickname"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" th:field="*{dog.name}" id="dog.name"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" th:field="*{dog.breed}" id="dog.breed"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" th:field="*{dog.dateOfBirth}" id="dog.dateOfBirth"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" th:field="*{dog.puppies}" id="dog.puppies"/></td>
            </form>
            </tr>
<tr  th:each="dog : ${dogs}">
       <td th:text="${dog.id}">1</td>
       <td th:text="${dog.nickname}"></td>
       <td th:text="${dog.name}"></td>
       <td th:text="${dog.breed}"></td>
       <td th:text="${dog.dateOfBirth}"></td>
       <td th:text="${dog.puppies}"></td>
        <br>
 </tr>
 </table>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Еще только что заметил, что Hibernate при старте приложения почему-то сам добавляет эту колонку

```
Hibernate: alter table if exists dogs add column breed smallint check (breed between 0 and 6)
```

Comment: Не додумался сразу просто удалить столбец и добавить заново. Пока сделаю так.

Comment: Не помогло `alter table dogs drop column breed; alter table dogs add column breed breed;` Ту же ошибку выдает

Comment: Еще только что заметил, что Hibernate при старте приложения почему-то сам добавляет эту `Hibernate: alter table if exists dogs add column breed smallint check (breed between 0 and 6)`

Answer (score 0):

Решением было в классе сущности `Dog` повесить на поле `private Breed breed;` аннотации `@Column(columnDefinition = "Breed") @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)`. Результат:

```
    @Column(columnDefinition = "Breed")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Breed breed;
```

Затем удалить столбец и перезапустить приложение - Hibernate сам создал правильный столбец.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15988342/mapping-enum-to-string-in-hibernate